# Derive the pdf and cdf of $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ have a uniform distribution on $\left [ 0,1 \right ] \times \left [ 0,1 \right ]$. I have to derive the cdf and pdf of $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$.

My attempt: Let $Z = \frac{X}{Y} \Leftrightarrow Y = Z^{-1} X$ for $Z \in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$.

Then $$G(z) = P(Z \leq z)$$
$$ = P\left ( Y \leq \frac{z^{-1}}{x} \right )$$
$$ = z^{-1} + \int_{z^{-1}}^{1} \int_{0}^{\frac{z^{-1}}{x}} dy dx$$
$$ = z^{-1} + z^{-1} (log 1 - log z^{-1})$$
$$ = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z} log\left ( \frac{1}{z} \right )$$

Does my work so far look correct?

Comment: $Z$ need not be in $[0,1]$, it will be a supported on the whole positive real line. Also, from $P(Z \leq z)$ you should get $P(X\leq zY)$ but you have got the other way round? From there none of the working has any meaning due to this mistake. Finally, are $X,Y$ independent? (This should be specified if it is the case)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes, I think $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables although it wasn't specified on the question.

Comment: All right, thank you , the answers below are satisfying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z$ defined on $(0, +\infty)$ (for any $z > 1$, pick $x = 1$ and $y=\frac{1}{z}$ to obtain $z = \frac{x}{y}$. for $z \in (0, 1)$ pick $x=y=z$)

Then,

$P(Z \le \alpha) = P(Y \ge \frac{X}{\alpha})$, this is a probability of all $(X, Y) \in [0,1]×[0,1]$ above line $Y = \frac{X}{\alpha}$.

Draw that line and compute the square of the area above that line, you'll get two cases

$$
P(Z \le \alpha)=
\begin{cases}
    \frac{\alpha}{2},& \text{if } \alpha\le 1\\
    1 - \frac{1}{2\alpha},              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
That's distribution function for $Z$.

[image]

You can notice CDF is differentiable everywhere including $1$, thus you can get pdf as well

Comment: If you could write some extra steps then I will appreciate it. I still quite don't understand how you obtained the CDF. Also would be helpful on showing me the pdf as well. I am not sure how it will work for a piecewise function.

Comment: define pdf as a piecewise as well

Comment: @govordovksy Thanks a lot man! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the pdf going to be this then? $$f(z) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0.5 & \text{if  } \alpha \leq 1\\ 
 \frac{1}{2 \alpha ^{2}}& \text{o.w.}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: @OGC, yes correct

Answer (score 2):

Note two bad signs - first, your CDF is not increasing with $z$. Second, it is not bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Note that $\frac{z^{-1}}{x}$ can be outside the region $[0,1]$, which should affect the limits of your integration. Moreover, in your second line of calculations, you should replace the direction of the $\leq$ sign.